# не отрабатывают чекбоксы в форме Angular2

Tags: checkbox, angular2, forms

Всем привет, помогите, плиз, разобраться, а то что-то не доходит до меня:

Есть компонент:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-analytics',
    templateUrl: './analytics.component.html',
    entryComponents: [DataRangeComponent]
})
export class AnalyticsComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    filter: FormGroup;
    constructor(private si: ScriptInjectorService, private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.filter = fb.group({
           'cmpBox': [true],
           'bnrBox': [false],
           'dayBox': [false],
           'siteBox': [false],
           'cntBox': [false]
        });
    }
}
```

В модуле этого компонента подключен FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule
Его темплейт:

```
<form [formGroup]="filter">
      <div class="form-group form-group-with-label">
        <label class="control-label">Group by</label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" name="camp" formControlName="cmpBox" /> Campaign
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" formControlName="bnrBox"/> Banner
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" formControlName="dayBox"/> Day
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" formControlName="siteBox"/> Site
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" formControlName="cntBox"/> Country
        </label>
     </div>
</form>
```

Сам Angular понимает что это - форма, он вешает на нее классы (1), но при клике на чекбоксе не срабатывает чейндж, и на каждом чекбоксе висит событие change от zone.js (2), если его убрать - все работает.

http://joxi.ru/ZrJV5gks9wN0wr

Внимание, вопрос: что я делаю не так, ведь по идее работать с формами не должно быть сколько-нибудь напряжно в Angular2. Просто подписка на valueChanged не срабатывает, данные не меняются.

Answer (score 0):

Не увидел где вы забираете значение модели filter, возможно вам поможет:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html#!#reactive

In two-way data binding, the user's changes flow automatically from the controls back to the data model properties. Reactive forms do not use data binding to update data model properties. The developer decides when and how to update the data model from control values.